# iphone: Facebook logout feature is not work in my app

Tags: iphone, xcode, facebook, ios5

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [iphone: facebook logout feature does not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11167593/iphone-facebook-logout-feature-does-not-working)

i am implementing FB integration through FBConnect 
It is not logout from Fb when i pressed logout button 
It only show previous Login..
My code is as follows:

```
- (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated
{

    [super viewWillAppear:animated];
    AppDelegate *delegate = (AppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];

    if (![[delegate facebook] isSessionValid]) {

    } else {
        [self showLoggedIn];
    }

}


- (IBAction)postMessageToWall:(id)sender {


        currentAPICall = kDialogFeedUser;
        SBJSON *jsonWriter = [[SBJSON new] autorelease];


        NSArray* actionLinks = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:[NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
                                                          @"TaxSmart Hello.",@"name",@"http://www.google.com",@"link", nil], nil];
        NSString *actionLinksStr = [jsonWriter stringWithObject:actionLinks];


        UIImage *img=[UIImage imageNamed:@"tick.png"];

        NSMutableDictionary *params = [NSMutableDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
                                       @"Piyush here.", @"name",
                                       @"This is Great App.", @"caption",
                                       @"FuNNNN.", @"description",
                                       @"http://www.iTaxsmart.com/", @"link",
                                       img.CIImage, @"picture",
                                       actionLinksStr, @"actions",
                                       nil];

        AppDelegate *delegate = (AppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
        [[delegate facebook] dialog:@"feed"
                          andParams:params
                        andDelegate:self];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

when you click on logout button call bellow method its work but just check your userdefault key..

```
- (void)fbDidLogout 
{    
    NSUserDefaults *defaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
    [facebook invalidateSession];
    [defaults removeObjectForKey:@"FBAccessTokenKey"];
    [defaults removeObjectForKey:@"FBExpirationDateKey"];
    [defaults synchronize];
}
```

hope,this help you.....

:)